# Dynamic data attributes

Tags: jquery, html

This is more of a 'can this happen' kind of question.

I'm setting local storage to remember what tabs the person was working on. My issue is that between the different projects they want to remember what they were doing in that specific project.

To save these tabs I'm setting a data attribute on the tab itself and then calling it with in the jQuery to show that tab above any other.

Ideally though I would like to have the data attributes to have dynamic names. I can set this easily enough in the html, by pulling in the project id, but I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to call that data attribute in the jQuery just using that one function.

So in my html I have something that looks like this

```
data-tab{{id}}="name"
```

and then I was calling them like this without the id. But now with the unique name I'm not really sure how to grab the attribute to call without replicating the function a billion times which is not really possible in this situation.

```
$(this).attr('data-tab');
```

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches a regular expression against all of attributes of an element and get the value of the first match.

```
var value = $(this.attributes).filter(function () {
    return this.name.match(/^data-tab/);
}).val();

alert(value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tN3gj/

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly try this way:

```
$.fn.getDynamicAttrVal = function(attrMatch){

  if(!attrMatch)return;

  var data = this.data(), //Get the data for the element
      keys = Object.keys(data), //Get all the keys which are attribute names
      value;


  $.each(keys, function(_, key){
    if(attrMatch.test(key)){ //Test for the pattern passed in against the key
      value =  data[key]; //If found get the value
      return false; //break the loop;
     }
  });

  return value;
}
```

and invoke it as :

```
$('elmSel').getDynamicAttrVal(/tab*/);
$('elmSel2').getDynamicAttrVal(/tab*/);
```

**[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/rirorita/1/)**

Comment: This solution is way neater than mine! Especially if @zazvorniki has more dynamic attributes besides just the `data-tab-` one.

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript the argument to `attr` is just a string. So if you want to use a dynamic name, just make a string:

```
var id = 6;

console.log( $(this).attr('data-tab' + id) );
// this is the same as .attr('data-tab6');
```

...or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Well, this would work if I only had a few id's, but I have a few thousand and it's always growing. I was really asking to do it dynamically so it could pull the id from the html somehow and then I could plug it in.

Comment: @zazvorniki It was just an example. I wasn't suggesting that you hard-code the `id` in your JavaScript. Of course you can get the `id` from the HTML, but you didn't give us any HTML to work with. Why not make a fiddle so we can see what you actually have?